# Keycloak mysql user storage

Tags: mysql, keycloak

I need to find or to create mysql user federation SPI for keycloak. A database already exists in my application, and I want to keycloak get user-info from the db.

I found an [example](https://github.com/kyrcha/keycloak-mysql-user-federation)
but when I try to add the federation, I have an exception
"Error! Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04sYC.png)

What I can to do, to fix it? Or maybe there is an explain/documents how to do it use different way.

Comment: See "Communications link failure, then it means that the DB isn't reachable at all." section in the highest voted answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found solution to my problem. I start mysql from docker container, and in this case, I should use 
jdbc:mysql://container_name:3306/my_app?user=root&password=root_password 
instead of 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_app?user=root&password=root_password